# Removing trailing slash from URL using PHP

Tags: php, redirect, trailing-slash

What I need:

`example.com/webpage/` should redirect to `example.com/webpage`

I am using:

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(substr($path, -1) == '/')
{
    $path=rtrim( $path, '/\\' );
    header("Location: $path");
}
```

The problem:

When someone requests the homepage (with or without trailing slash), the value of `$path` becomes `'/'` and it causes a loop. Can anyone offer me a better solution?

Comment: Just add another check: `if($path !== '/' && substr($path, -1) == '/')`

Comment: Check the .htacess file.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = preg_replace('#/\s*$#', '', $path);
header("Location: $path");
```

Comment: This will _always_ redirect. Wouldn't that cause an infinite loop? `REQUEST_URI == '/'` results in an empty `Location:` header. Is that even valid?